# Existence and Uniqueness of Solution to PDE using Banach Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, dispersive-pde

I am studying some results about existence and uniqueness of solutions to some PDEs and many times Banach fixed point Theorem is used. I saw that the ideia is to consider the integral formulation and use the Theorem to prove existence and uniqueness in a ball but I can't understant how the uniquess extends to all the space.

Any one can explain how to get uniquess in all the space and how existence and uniquess of solution to the integral formulation garantees the same for the PDE?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a representative equation or example? Existence and uniqueness for PDEs caries wildly depending on the specific equation

Comment: Sure. I am reading the part of Schrodinger equation in Lineares and Ponce's book, Introduction to nonlinear dispersive equations. To prove local existence in $L^{2}$ they use Banach fixed point only a ball and conclude the existence and uniqueness in all space.

Comment: you’re confusing things. The Banach’s fixed point theorem is applied to a ball in the function space, not a ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$. The function space is defined to be a subset of functions with domain all of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Banach's fixed point garantees the existence and uniqueness of solution in a ball in $L^2$. My doubt is how this implies the uniqueness in all $L^2$.